# Need Help With Greater Than and maybe Less Than Value In Drivers (FIXED)

Tags: drivers

So I am making a driver that enables a object if a value is above -0.25 and disables if it's above -0.49 but I have a monkey brain and don't understand the math needed to do this, if anyone can figure out how to actually do this that'll be great (current code used below)

`1 if value > -0.25 and location < -0.49 else 0`

NOTE: Helped by Shantanu Aryan, if I knew how to accept a answer I would go with that one

Comment: what if value is between -0.25 and -0.49?

Comment: that's a better way to describe it, but I can't figure out how to actually make it only appear between -0.25 and -0.49

Comment: you can just use the conditional statement as the expression. eg `value > -0.49 and value < -0.25` this will return a True/False value. if you set this as the driver of `Disable in Render` button, when true will mean the object is hidden. you can reverse that with `not (value > -0.49 and value < -0.25)`

Comment: Does value = location? Why are both used?

Comment: THANK YOU! if I knew how I would mark your answer as accepted